# Implementing RadioButton inside DialogFragment using onCreateView

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, android-dialogfragment

I've been trying to implement RadioButton functionality within a DialogFragment, where the values are stored/displayed via a Button click.

Here's the code I've assembled so far. Can anyone help me out with what I'm doing wrong and what I should probably be doing? Thank you.

```
    public class AddDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static RadioGroup addRadioGroup;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_layout, container);

        Button dialogAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_add_button);
        dialogAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText addInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.add_input);
                int selected_id = addRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton addRadioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selected_id);
                Toast.makeText(this, addRadioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        this.getDialog().setTitle("Set Title");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `RadioGroup addRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RADIO_BUTTON_ID);`

```
public class AddDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_layout, container);

        Button dialogAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_add_button);
        RadioGroup addRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RADIO_BUTTON_ID);
        dialogAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText addInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.add_input);
                int selected_id = addRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton addRadioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selected_id);
                Toast.makeText(this, addRadioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        this.getDialog().setTitle("Set Title");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final" warning for both "view" as well as "addRadioGroup".